# annoying line-break in IRB (pry) when returning to command

Tags: ruby, irb, pry

I've been experiencing this problem for quite a long time and have been searching for a solution, but unfortunately I couldn't find anything helpful online.

When using IRB or PRY console with Ruby on OS X, it happens that when I want to return to some long command that I previously entered (using arrow up), the command will mess up the whole line, in which it should be written. This way I cannot see the line correctly or change it. Sometimes it moving to a new line (using Ctrl+C), sometimes it doesn't.

Here is an example of what I mean:
[image: console typing issue]

The problem is really frustrating, because it's forcing me into writing the commands again or using an external clip-board.

How can this be fixed?

Thank you!